# Android app with google Signin : authentication flow

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-oauth

Hi I'm trying to implement a google sign-in with my app and make it so that only authenticated users can do calls to my Rest API i build for the app.

Currently I have this in mind but I don't know if it's correct and safe :

1. User signs in with android app
2. android app sends idToken to backend
3. backend verifies the user idToken and saves the id(is included in the token according to google documentation) in the database along with the basic profile info

   #

Now that the user is registered with the back-end , do we have to re-do this check for every call the users makes to the Rest API ? or is it safe to use the id we got with the token ?

If we go this route of 'passing some sort of authentication id for the api to check' every call , we have to save it in the app , right ?

I'm kinda confused about the oAuth 2 system with an app and backend

Comment: Digital Ocean has a really great guide on OAuth2. Read it here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: Ya, once you authenticate the user, you will have to set up some kind of session management: e.g. a set a cookie to pass and validate with their requests (as you'd do for a website user session), or issue your own OAuth tokens to the client app and manage with each backend request, or just fetch an ID token each time and use that as authorization for each request (would work fine if you only use Google Sign-In and not other types of authentication). You can't submit the plaintext ID as authorization (it's not a secret and spoofable). Let me know if that helps point you in the right direction

Comment: your comment and the article will help me on my way :) thanks for the reply !